# error al llamar Servlet desde index.jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

Buenas tardes, tengo un proble al llamar un servlet desde mi index.jsp, dentro del index tengo un formulario

> index.jsp

```html
<form action="ServletLogin" role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                Usuario</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtUsuario" id="txtUsuario" placeholder="Usuario" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                                Contraseña</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Contraseña" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-7">
                                                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</a>
                                                <a class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Entrar</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ServletLogin.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            Privilegio pv = new Privilegio();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

            String tipo_usuario;
            int num_empleado = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtUsuario"));
            String password = request.getParameter("txtxPassword");

            tipo_usuario = pv.autenticar(num_empleado, password);

            session.setAttribute("tipo_usuario", tipo_usuario);

            response.sendRedirect("jefe.jsp");
        }
    }
```

> web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletLogin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.ServletLogin</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletLogin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletLogin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Javier pero donde esta la llamada al servlet?

Comment: Hola, lo estoy llamando en action="ServletLogin" del formulario

Answer (score 1):

Que tal,como tienes configurado tu "ServletLogin" en tu proyecto?

esta es la forma en la cual configuro un servlet para posteriormente invocarlo.
1) crear la clase servlet en este caso tu creaste "ServletLogin", en esa clase contiene los metodos doGet(),doPost(), supongo estas usando el doPost() ya que en tu formulario declaraste method="POST"
2) en el web.xml que por lo regular se encuentra en WEB-INF/web.xml
    necesitas agregar la configuración siguiente de tu servlet:

```
      <servlet> <servlet-name>ServletLogin</servlet-name>  <servlet-class>paquete.ServletLogin</servlet-class></servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>ServletLogin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletLogin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

3) en el metodo doPost(): 
   obtienes los valores String email =request.getParameter("email");

No se si falte alguna configuración en tu proyecto.
Saludos.

Comment: pero ni siquiera esta accionando el boton cuando lo presiono

Comment: cambia : <a class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Entrar</a> por <input type="submit" value ="Entrar"/>

Comment: esque no me esta accionando el boton de mi index.jsp y no manda a ningun otro lado ni manda error, cuando lo presiono es como si no pasara nada

Comment: @Javierfr Lo que pasa, es que un <input> o <button> con el type="submit" son los unicos que pueden triggeriar el formulario, al menos que uses javascript con el evento onCliclk.

Comment: ya sustitui tu tu imput y tampoco

Comment: <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="Entrar"> este input debería de generar un boton en tu formulario, podrías mostrar tu configuración del web.xml del servlet?

Comment: si deja agrego el codigo

Comment: ya agregue mi web.xml

Comment: No veo nada raro en web.xml, ahora los métodos de tu servlet, a parte del que muestras hay otros ?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el form estas mandando la información como POST, en tu servlet tendrías que obtenerlo de la misma manera.

Comment: encontre algo sospechoso, esque ese formulario esta en una modal entonces lo que hise fue crear un proyecto nuevo pero unicamente puse el formulario sin diseño y sin nada y si manda, que podra ser?

Comment: Si es algo sospechoso en teoría no debería de afectarle, otro modo de generar el submit es con javascript o jquery, te lo recomiendo mucho es usando un ajax, deja añado un ejemplo.

Comment: si, muchas gracias

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue, en teria lo que hace es generar un evento con javascript al darle click al elemento <a onClick="funcion()"> entra a la función y dentro de la función se genera una petición  al servlet con ajax, la ventajas de esto es que no te refresca toda la pantalla como en el submit, trabajas por secciones.

Answer (score 1):

Usando Ajax(Necesitas jquery):

1)  En tu boton del submit: `<a onClick="Entrar()" class="btn btn-dark" > Entrar</a>`
2) en un archivo .js agregas la funcion Entrar().

```
  function Entrar(){
      $.ajax({  
                url:"/ServletLogin", 
                type:'POST',
                data:{txtUsuario:$("#txtUsuario").val(),txtPassword:$("#txtPassword").val()},
                success: function( resp ) {
               //aqui obtienes la respuesta de tu servlet
                },
                error:function(error){
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no estás usando ninguna llamada javascript, y realizás las llamadas por el formulario lo único que tenes que hacer es dejar los dos métodos originales **doGet()** y **doPost()**, vos le pusiste **processRequest()**, cambiálo por **doPost()** porque en tu form html lo declaraste como **method="post"**, **eso sólo tenés que hacer**, si las rutas de los servlet están bien declaradas no tendrías más problemas.

Por **defecto** desde un **form html** si no hacés ninguna llamada javascript, el form **sólo acepta get y post** que condice con **doGet()** y **doPost()** de los servlets.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            Privilegio pv = new Privilegio();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

            String tipo_usuario;
            int num_empleado = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtUsuario"));
            String password = request.getParameter("txtxPassword");

            tipo_usuario = pv.autenticar(num_empleado, password);

            session.setAttribute("tipo_usuario", tipo_usuario);

            response.sendRedirect("jefe.jsp");
        }
    }
```

En el caso que el cambio de nombre que te comenté **no funcione**, podés probar un cambio mínimo que **seguro va a funcar**. Realizando una **llamada** muy muy simple por **javascript** y sin ningun framework.

Sólo tenés que **agregar esta llamada** en algún lugar de tu html, **agregarle** la etiqueta **name** a tu **form** html y por último **cambiar el botón** del form por el tag html, empieza tag **button value="Enviar" onclick="ajaxCall()"**, termina tag.

**Te dejo hecho en código.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- LLamada ajax javascript puro -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxCall(){
    var frm = document.frmServletLogin;
    frm.submit();
}
</script>


<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Acá le agregamos la etiqueta name, para que tome el valor en la llamada js -->
    <form action="ServletLogin" name="frmServletLogin" role="form" method="post"class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Usuario</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtUsuario"
                    id="txtUsuario" placeholder="Usuario" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Contraseña</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtPassword"
                    id="txtPassword" placeholder="Contraseña" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-7">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</a>
                <!-- Cambiamos el boton anterior por este que referencia a una function javascript por medio del onclick -->
                <button value="Enviar" onclick="ajaxCall()">Entrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Fijate que le dimos un nombre al form, luego hicimos una llamada ajax, en la misma creamos una variable con la ruta document.frmLogin(html donde se trabaja seguido por el name del frm), luego el submit(), que envía todos los parámetros si existiesen;

**No te olvides de cambiarle el nombre al método** que **espera** la **llamada** desde el **jsp/html**, obviamente podés tener más métodos que hagan muchas cosas dentro del servlet, no es muy recomendable pero se puede, lo que **por costumbre** se mantienen en este tipo de sistema es de que **los dos métodos** que existan dentro de un **servlet** sean principalmente **doGet()** y **doPost()**.

Answer (score -1):

Si estas usando Java Server Pages lo correcto es usar:

```
<jsp:include page=" URLdeServlet " />
```

Pero veo que estas usando en realidad un `html`, entonces en el `action` del `form` define el url del `servlet`, de esta forma:

```
<form action=" URLdeServlet " role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

Comment: arriva de mi index.jsp tengo lo sieguiente

Comment: <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>